# pyparsing retrieve resulting keys for strings of dynamic length

Tags: python, iterator, pyparsing

I try to parse a list of groups in `pyparsing`. These groups may be of different type and I would like to retrieve the type in my result. As there may be multiple groups of the same type a dictionary does not help.
To illustrate my problem I give a minimal example:

```
import pyparsing as pars

dot = pars.Literal(".")
question = pars.Literal("?")
comma = pars.Literal(",")

total = pars.OneOrMore(
    pars.Group(
        pars.OneOrMore(dot)("dot")
        | pars.OneOrMore(question)("question")
    )
    + pars.Optional(comma)
)

result = total.parseString("...,?????,..,??")
```

So a sequence of dots form a group and a sequence of questionmarks form a group. Thus I named these groups `dot` and `question`.
The resulting dictionary however

```
In: result.asDict()
Out: {}
```

If I print this as `XML`:

```
<ITEM>
  <dot>
    <dot>.</dot>
    <ITEM>.</ITEM>
    <ITEM>.</ITEM>
  </dot>
  <ITEM>,</ITEM>
  <question>
    <question>?</question>
    <ITEM>?</ITEM>
    <ITEM>?</ITEM>
    <ITEM>?</ITEM>
    <ITEM>?</ITEM>
  </question>
  <ITEM>,</ITEM>
  <dot>
    <dot>.</dot>
    <ITEM>.</ITEM>
  </dot>
  <ITEM>,</ITEM>
  <question>
    <question>?</question>
    <ITEM>?</ITEM>
  </question>
</ITEM>
```

Apart from the weird naming of the sub-items, the group tag has the correct name. My question is, how can I iterate through this result without using this xml. I mean, `.asList()` drops the keys, `.asDict()` discards multiple items of the same type and `.asXML()` returns a String. Isn't there a way to obtain all tuples like so:

```
for k,v in GETMYTUPLES:
    print k, v
    -> dot [".", ".", "."]
    -> question ["?", ... and so forth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally discourage use of the `asXML()` method - it is deprecated and will probably go away in version 2.2.  If you use `dump()` instead, you will see that what you have is a sequence of named groups, not a dict, so `asDict()`, which only gives output for the keyed values, has nothing to work with at the top level.

```
print(result.dump())

[['.', '.', '.'], ',', ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'], ',', ['.', '.'], ',', ['?', '?']]
[0]:
  ['.', '.', '.']
  - dot: ['.', '.', '.']
[1]:
  ,
[2]:
  ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']
  - question: ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']
[3]:
  ,
[4]:
  ['.', '.']
  - dot: ['.', '.']
[5]:
  ,
[6]:
  ['?', '?']
  - question: ['?', '?']
```

To get each parsed bit, rather than calling `asDict()` or `asList()`, just iterate over the result directly. If you call `asDict()` on each of the list elements, you will see your named values:

```
for r in result:
    if isinstance(r, pars.ParseResults):
        print(r.asDict())

{'dot': ['.', '.', '.']}
{'question': ['?', '?', '?', '?', '?']}
{'dot': ['.', '.']}
{'question': ['?', '?']}
```

You can also use `getName()` for those sub elements:

```
for r in result:
    if isinstance(r, pars.ParseResults):
        print(r, r.getName())

['.', '.', '.'] dot
['?', '?', '?', '?', '?'] question
['.', '.'] dot
['?', '?'] question
```

**EDIT**

Also, consider replacing:

```
total = pars.OneOrMore(
    pars.Group(
        pars.OneOrMore(dot)("dot")
        | pars.OneOrMore(question)("question")
    )
    + pars.Optional(comma)
)
```

with

```
total = delimitedList(pars.Group(pars.OneOrMore(dot)("dot") | 
                                 pars.OneOrMore(question)("question"))))
```

When you have a list of things delimited by commas, the commas are usually there to help at parse time, but afterward, what you really want are just the things. `delimitedList` does that for you (comma is the default delimiter, but you can pass a different one as the optional `delim` parameter).